# How to iterate json and save to list?

Tags: java, arrays, json, loops, arraylist

I have a situation in which my json array has more than one key within an array like this...

```
"information"{
     "info": [
   {
    "name": "Susan",
    "address": "101 Blue Street",
    },
    
   {
    "name": "John",
    "address": "203 Red Street",
  }
 ]
 }
```

I have no problem getting both names if I do this...

```
     String firstName = firstObject.getJSONArray("info").optJSONObject(0).optString("name");
     String secondName = firstObject.getJSONArray("info").optJSONObject(1).optString("name");
```

However, there is no guarantee that only two objects will be returned so I am now attempting
to loop through these items and saving to arraylist for further processing.

Below is what I have so far.  I'm getting the names (nameString) but they are not saving to the list.  The list clears on next iteration.

What am I doing wrong?

```
     JSONObject firstObject = response.optJSONObject("information");
     JSONArray infoArray = firstObject.getJSONArray("info");

     String nameString;
     String save;
     List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> al2 = new ArrayList<>();


     for(int index = 0; index < infoArray.length(); index++) {
         JSONObject jsonObject = infoArray.getJSONObject(index);
         nameString = jsonObject.getString("name");
         System.out.println("name: " + nameString);
         
         
         al = Arrays.asList(nameString);
         
         for(String s: al){
            
           log.info("nameString  " + s);
          
          save = s;
         al2.add(save);
```

Comment: Your code is missing some brackets. Could you please write the full code for the entire class?

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185839/how-to-get-array-from-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration your are creating a new ArrayList from the nameString. You should simply add to the existing list instead:

`al.add(nameString);`

Comment: Thanks.  Guess I needed a second pair of eyes.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You have already got the name in the line
`nameString = jsonObject.getString("name")`
There is no need to use the second for loop. Just add the nameString object into the list. `al.add(nameString)`  will save the name in to the list.